# Python file issue from root path

Tags: scripting, backup, python

I have a script that is well-tested and known to be working. I am running into an issue with it where when I try to run it from `/root/backup/script.py` or `~/backup/script.py` I get a file not found error from the script when it runs and looks for other files called from within the script. It works on other machines but settings are the same and it works if I am in my home directory and run `python backup/script.py` or run it directly with `python script.py` it works. The files it is trying to get are inside the same directory as script.py so I can't see what's wrong. It works to get the first file the script calls but fails to get this one.

I am thinking it could be some kind of path issue as it works on other systems if it is done the same way.

**EDIT**

after reading the first comment I have posted the code snippet that is falling over and realised that the first file is also not being found like I said it was sorry for the mistake here is the code. As I said above it works from other location but not the two I mentioned.

```py
storage = Storage("user_creds.dat")
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = run_flow(flow_from_clientsecrets("client_secrets.json", OAUTH_SCOPE, ), storage, fla$
```

Comment: It may be helpful to post a simplified version of the script that only reproduces the problem; at least post the lines that look for the files that can't be found

Comment: Ok I have added code to the question that causes my issue with the two paths. The functions called are taken from the Google API python client

Comment: What directory is `user_creds.dat` in?

Comment: The same directory as script.py thats where all files are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file not found error may be due to you launching the script from different directories.

```py
storage = Storage("user_creds.dat")
```

will only find `user_creds.dat` if the script is launched *from* that directory, e.g.,

```
]$ pwd
~/backup
]$ python script.py
```

---

If you need to be able to launch the script from anywhere, you can specify an absolute path to `user_creds.dat`.  Alternatively, you can use the following to get the directory that the script is located:

```py
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

You can then get your Storage object with

```py
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'user_creds.dat')
```

Comment: Assuming that the Storage class is an extension of a file object (as I couldn't find it in the standard docs), this being the problem can be checked by printing ` os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(storage))` post-assignment. Because yay, debugging?

Comment: Looks like it was due to different directories don't think the script likes absolute directories as it works fine with relative but fixed now. Thanks.